# How can i get screen capture?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios6

I am working on video and audio merging app. My work is to play 3 videos at a time that I did already by AVPlayer class.

but when I take screen capture of that background video in which I've added 3 videos then I am not able to make one video.

I am using `UIGetScreenImage();`

```
    CALayer *layer;

    layer = self.view.layer;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(768, 950));
    CGContextClipToRect (UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),CGRectMake(0, 64, 768, 950));
    [layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    image   = [self imageWithImage:image convertToSize:CGSizeMake(768, 872)];
```

Thanks

Comment: sorry, didn't get you.

Comment: UIGetScreenImage() is a private API and your app will risk appstore rejection (if you are going to deploy on AppStore)

Comment: Sir i want to make screen recording when AVPlayer plays some video so, it should look like one video from many videos.

Comment: Hi Andrea and HariKrishnan please help me out to solve that issue.